# How do I programmatically change the workflow status?

Tags: 7, workflows

It appears that, although Drupal 6 had `workflow_transition()`, that function is not available in Drupal 7.

Is there an equivalent function? If not, what else should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workflow_transition()` is a function implemented from the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module, and [it still is implemented in the Drupal 7 version of the module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/workflow/-/blob/7.x-1.x/workflow.module#L254).

Drupal 6 code that used `workflow_transition()` would work in Drupal 7
without changing how that function is called.